# Can't launch Eclipse

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse for quite a while. I just switched from OpenJDK to SunJDK. I went back to using Eclipse, it opened just fine. I added some libraries to my build path of a project, but the error checker was still saying I didn't have it. So I decided to restart Eclipse. After than I can't start eclipse. It doesn't give any errors or anything. If I launch it from the command line, it doesn't do anything:

```
joel@joel-laptop:~$ eclipse
joel@joel-laptop:~$
```

It never pops up the choose workbench dialog or anything.
Has anyone heard of this? I'm using the latest version from the Ubuntu repos.

I've tried restarting my machine and reinstalling Eclipse. Nothing.

Comment: `eclipse -consoleLog` might get you some information?

Comment: I ended up purging eclipse and Sun's JDK then reinstalled eclipse (which ended up reinstalling OpenJDK) And it works again. Weird.

Comment: Maybe you hit the "Oracle Bug"? I thought it was Windows only and had already been fixed, you never know though. FYI amusing details here http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/oracle-rebrands-java-breaks-eclipse/2012

Comment: @richq, hardly, unless Joel installed Java directly from Sun.  The Ubuntu repository trails a bit behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used apt-get purge eclipse and then apt-get install eclipse and it still did the same thing. I ended up purging Sun JDK and reinstalling Eclipse and it installed OpenJDK. All works again.

However, I'm a little disappointed that it wasn't working with Sun JDK. Oh well. Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

UNless you have good reason to, I have found that the best way to run Eclipse is to download it from eclipse.org, and not install the one in the Ubuntu repositories.  Uninstall the repository version, and download one manually and run it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a log in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log that you can check although I don't think that's going to work in your case. Also what do you mean you reinstalled eclipse? are you using synaptic or just unzipping into a directory? try `which eclipse` in case you have many installed to see which is being executed.

check if setting up the JRE manually using the -vm parameter in eclipse.ini changes thing.

Comment: "I'm using the latest version from the Ubuntu repos." I used `apt-get purge eclipse` and then `apt-get install eclipse` and it still did the same thing. I ended up purging Sun JDK and reinstalling Eclipse and it installed OpenJDK. All works again.

Comment: I have used Eclipse with both OpenJDK and the Sun VM. For me, the Sun VM always had the better performance (which could also be measured using profilers). Therefore you might want to give another try if you use large workspaces in Eclipse.