# Problem installing eclipse-platform

Tags: 10.10, apt, java, eclipse

I am trying to install the eclipse-platform package in a new Ubuntu 10.10 and I am getting the following error (via the Ubuntu software center):

```
Failed to fetch http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libservlet2.4-java/libservlet2.4-java_5.0.30-12_all.deb
404  Not Found
```

Browsing to the mentioned URL, I can obviously verify that the .deb file in question is missing.

Is the package broken, or is it just the NZ mirror?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice discussion between Raphael B. and Stefano Palazzo as to which method *is recommended*. However, neither says *by whom*. I, however, will give *my* recommendation, with no intention of being the generally correct answer for everybody.

I have *always* installed my own private version of Eclipse for a number of reasons:

1. It’s ridiculously simple.
2. The packaged version will always lag behind a bit, and I want the cutting edge. I also have to align with other people in my shop.
3. It allows me to have several Eclipse installations side-by-side, each with a different set of plugins, since it often is a bad idea to include every plugin under the sun (oh, an unintended pun) into one Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the mirror. The German mirror is fine: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libservlet2.4-java/libservlet2.4-java_5.0.30-12_all.deb

But, it's not recommended to use the packaged version. [Continue reading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2216/cant-launch-eclipse) and download Eclipse and unzip it in your preferred directory -- it's really simple by this [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just the mirror, as I have it installed (and up to date) on my machine.  Although I would recommend just getting the package from the eclipse website itself: http://eclipse.org/ .  It comes with the latest version that isn't in the repos.